# Primefaces commandButton inside dialog not firing backing bean's method

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I've just started learning JSF and PrimeFaces, and as soon as I solve a problem (with your help), another one arises. I have a datatable showing some data about my application's users; in the last column, a commandButton invokes a dialog allowing the corresponding data to be edited. The dialog actually interacts with the backing bean, since the fields are correctly precompiled with the existing data, but the "Submit changes" commandButton doesn't fire the proper `editUser()` method!

I've searched everywhere for a solution to my problem, but none of the threads on the PrimeFaces forums nor any question here on Stack Overflow helped me: I tried all combinations of `action`, `actionListener`, inner `<h:form>`, outer `<h:form>`, even the dreaded nested `<h:form>`, but the underlying method is still not called.

Thank you all, people!

**EDIT**: I included some more xhtml. Just to be clear: in the datatable I'm implementing both single and multiple selection mechanisms. The single selection is performed by the `editButton` in the last column and triggers the `editDialog` that's giving me pain, while multiple selection is enabled by the checkboxes in the first column and is targeted by a commandButton at the bottom of the table that deletes all selected users; of course they store the selections in different fields in the backing bean (`selectedUser` and `selectedUsers[]`, respectively).

**xhtml file**

```
<h:form id="tableForm">
    <p:dataTable id="userList" var="user" value="#{userListBean.userList}"
        selection="#{userListBean.selectedUsers}" rowKey="#{user.username}">

        <!-- this is a checkbox column I use for multiple selection -->
        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%"/>

        <!-- other datatable columns -->

        <!-- this is the button column that triggers the dialog -->
        <p:column style="width:4%">
            <p:commandButton id="editButton" update=":tableForm:editUserData"
                oncomplete="PF('editDialog').show()" title="Edit" icon="ui-icon-pencil">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{userListBean.selectedUser}"
                    value="#{user}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:datatable>

    <p:dialog id="editDlg" widgetVar="editDialog" header="Edit User"
        showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" modal="true" dynamic="true">
        <h:panelGrid columns="6" id="editUserData">

            <p:outputLabel for="editUsername">Username:</p:outputLabel>
            <p:inputText disabled="true" id="editUsername" value="#{userListBean.selectedUser.username}" />
            <p:message for="editUsername" />

            <!-- and other fields like that -->

        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton id="submitChanges" action="#{userListBean.editUser()}"
            value="Submit changes" oncomplete="PF('editDialog').hide();" /> 
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

**Backing bean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="userListBean")
@ViewScoped
public class UserListBean {
    private UserDTO selectedUser;

    public UserListBean() {

    }

    //some methods...

    public String editUser() {
        System.out.println("------------------ EDIT TRIGGERED! -------------------");
        System.out.println(selectedUser.getUsername());
        //this stuff never gets printed, so the method is never called!
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could post more of your xhtml

Comment: Added more xhtml and some additional notes! Thank you again. @LeonardoKenji

Comment: Dialog must have its own form.

Comment: Actually, @BalusC, I figured it out! I had already tried putting the dialog in its own separate form, as well as keeping the dialog out of forms and putting one _inside_ the dialog, but with no success. I've laid out the arrangement that worked for me in my answer. Many thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the only thing didn't come to my mind turned out to be the one that worked.
I sorted out my issue by using THREE forms (as I mentioned in my question, I had already tried out all possible combinations of one and two forms, even nested ones), like this:

```
<h:form id="tableForm">
    <!-- here lies the p:dataTable -->
</h:form>

<p:dialog>
    <h:form id="dialogForm">
        <!-- here lies the h:panelGrid with the editable fields -->
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="buttonForm">
        <!-- and HERE goes the commandButton, alone -->
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

It looks like everyone solves this problem in ways that don't work for others :) .

Comment: This won't submit the data from editable fields. That this "works" for you in turn suggests that there's a validation/conversion error in one of those editable fields for which you never displayed the faces message.

Comment: Putting the commandButton directly under the form tag worked for me as well.  Cheers.